# HTML5 History API - store a div in pushState

Tags: javascript, html, pushstate, popstate

There are two things that are dynamic: a navigation div, and a content div. Instead of storing both, my plan is to store the entire body div in the first parameter of `pushState`.

What is the proper way to store the data? I have tried the following which products an error `Uncaught DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': An object could not be cloned.`:

```
history.pushState($('.body-content'), newTitle, newURL);
```

This is how it's going to handle popstate, untested:

```
    window.onpopstate = function (event) {
        updateContent(event.state);
    };

    function updateContent(data) {
        if (data == null)
            return;

        $('.body-content').html(data);
    }
```

**edit**: Adding `.html()` to the jQuery selector worked:

```
history.pushState($('.body-content').html(), 'testTitle', getURL(newQuery));
```

But popstates are still inconsistent, currently looking into this further. I suspect that the data is being restored to the wrong level in the nest of div's, and the Leaflet map will have stale variables that should've also been saved in the pushState.

Comment: So it's working now since you edited your question?

Comment: The Dom is restored, but not the JS variables

Comment: Not the JS variables? You mean that you also store javascript variables inside that div and try to put them back?

Comment: No, I mean the state of the Leaflet map and Slick carousel, they need to be initialized. I think I know how to do this in concept, I will try again and report back.

Comment: @BramHammer It's somewhat working now. Essentially, I'm not storing anything through the History API, but only through the URL. When a user returns to a previous URL, that state is shown again by setting the appropriate div to visible, and generating the content of that div if it does not already exist or does not match the url's ID. The problem now is that it can only go back one page, and it cannot go forward again... I can't figure out why.